# java why is this method not visible

Tags: java

Why is `getPlatformId()` not visible to `SalesforcePlatform` in the subclass method `getPlatformName()`? The code block is not complete. `SalesforcePlatform` is a child of `Platform`. It is in a different package than `Platform`, but that should not prevent it from accessing Platform's protected method, right?

Sorry if I missed something obvious.

```
package com.dragon.dictionary;

public class Platform extends RepositoryObject
  implements IPlatform{

  protected final Long id ;
  protected final String  name;
  protected static final String platformDbTbl = DragonConstants.TABLE_PREFIX + "platform";


  protected Platform(Long platformId, String platformName){
    id = platformId;
    name = platformName;
  };

  protected Platform(String platformName){
    Platform platform = Platform.getPlatformByName(platformName);
    id = platform.getPlatformId();
    name = platformName;
  };

  protected Long getPlatformId(){
    return this.id;
  };

  protected String getPlatformName(){
    return this.name;
  }

  ....

}




package com.dragon.dictionary.salesforce;

import com.dragon.dictionary.Platform;

public class SalesforcePlatform extends Platform{

  // prevent instantiation
  private SalesforcePlatform() {
    super("salesforce");
  }

  private SalesforcePlatform(Long platformId, String platformName) {
    super(platformId, platformName);
  }  

  public static SalesforcePlatform getPlatformByName(String platformName){
    Platform platform = Platform.getPlatformByName(platformName);
    SalesforcePlatform salesforcePlatform = new SalesforcePlatform(platform.getPlatformId(), platform.getPlatformName());
    return salesforcePlatform;
  }
}
```

EDIT:

Thanks! So based on the responses, are you saying, this would have worked in the subclass:

```
  private SalesforcePlatform(Platform platform) {
    this.id = platform.getPlatformId();
    this.name = platform.getPlatformName();
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

You are not calling the protected method from a sub-class, but from a static method.
The fact that the static method is defined in the sub-class is irrelevant.

Edit:

> Thanks! So based on the responses, are you saying, this would have worked in the sub class

That new updated code has two problems:
- Your `PlatForm` class has no default constructor, so you need to call the super constructor and pass the arguments
- The fields you are trying to assign are final. They will already be set by your super class constructor.

Comment: Plausible.  However, the OP didn't show us the calling code so we can't be absolutely certain about this.

Comment: @StephenC he showed us `SalesforcePlatform salesforcePlatform = new SalesforcePlatform(platform.getPlatformId(), platform.getPlatformName());` in the static context, and that was the only occurrence of `getPlatformId`. So I assumed that was the problem

Comment: Thanks @Robin I ended up changing the protected methods to public -

Comment: Although I am still struggling - I realize now that with the protected modifier, I can only access the inherited members referred to as the child's members even in the child code? So if c extends a that has a member x, I can only access it as c.x even in c's code?

Comment: @Robin - sorry you are right.  I somehow missed the scroll-bar.

Answer (score 2):

The rule says:

> A protected member or constructor of an object may be accessed from outside the package in which it is declared only by code that is responsible for the implementation of that object.

See [here for the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.2).